# Where do i see postgres username and password

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have installed Postgres with Homebrew, and it didn't ask me to setup any username and password. Now I am having troubles connect the ruby project with db. I don't know what username and password to use in config file.

I checked my pg_hba.conf file, all methods are set to trust, and user is mostly set to all or my profile name.

When I start Rails, the server starts and then gives PG::ConnectionBad error.

I am new to Ruby and all this and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Please show the full, exact text of the error message. If you're using `trust` then you don't need to supply *any* password, and the username can be any username defined in the PostgreSQL server. The default user is `postgres`, but you should `CREATE USER` a different user for applications.

Comment: Yes, but i couldnt create it, it was saying pg cannot be find. I solved the issue with uninstalling the postgresql with brew and then installing it back. it was saying my port 5432 is already in use, until i restarted my machine, then all worked fine. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you checked any docs before posting, default user is `postgres`, but check if postgres service is running `ps aux | grep postgres` and follow [this doc](http://blog.willj.net/2011/05/31/setting-up-postgresql-for-ruby-on-rails-development-on-os-x/) to perform all required setup. [First steps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_steps) are also worth your attention.